# The method updateStatus(String) in the type TweetRecources is not applicable for the argument (String[])

Tags: java, twitter, arguments, processing

I'm currently using processing to create an interface that allows the user to enter text into a text box (using controlP5 library), which then gets sent to twitter. But the following error message keeps getting displayed: The method updateStatus(String) in the type TweetRecources is not applicable for the argument (String[]). Any ideas of how this could get fixed?
code:

```
import controlP5.*;
PImage twitterBird;

// import twitter4j library
import twitter4j.conf.*;
import twitter4j.*;
import twitter4j.auth.*;
import twitter4j.api.*;

// use the List and Date class when dealing with tweets
import java.util.*;

Twitter twitter;    // create instance of Twitter object

ControlP5 cp5;

String[] newTweet = {"Please Enter Tweet"};

void setup() {
  background(255);
  size(900,600);

// Authentication on Twitter
// see information sheet "Twitter Apps" to find out how to get these details
ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
cb.setOAuthConsumerKey("*Customer key*");
cb.setOAuthConsumerSecret("*Consumer Secret*");
cb.setOAuthAccessToken("Access Token");
cb.setOAuthAccessTokenSecret("Token Secret");

// create TwitterFactory object and pass the configuration
TwitterFactory tf = new TwitterFactory(cb.build());

// Initialise Twitter object by retrieving instance from the TwitterFactory
twitter = tf.getInstance();

  twitterBird = loadImage("twitterBird.jpg");

  PFont font = createFont("arial",25);

  cp5 = new ControlP5(this);

  int y = 260;
  int spacing = 90;
  for(String name: newTweet){
    cp5.addTextfield(name)
       .setPosition(200,y)
       .setSize(500,60)
       .setColorBackground(0xffffffff)
       .setFont(font)
       .setFocus(true)
       .setColor(color(10,10,255))
       ;
     y += spacing;
  }

  textFont(font);
}

void draw() {

  image(twitterBird, 150, 0, 615, 292);

  if(keyPressed==true){
    if(key == '\n'){
      tweet();
    }
  }

  }


void tweet()
{
    // try to send tweet
    try 
    {
        Status status = twitter.updateStatus(newTweet);
        System.out.println("Status updated to [" + status.getText() + "].");
    }
    // tell us if try fails
    catch (TwitterException te)
    {
        System.out.println("Error: "+ te.getMessage()); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error message says, you are passing an **array** of `String` as argument to a method that accepts a single `String`.

Where you did:

```
String[] newTweet = {"Please Enter Tweet"};
```

Since this is an array with only one element, you probably want:

```
String newTweet = "Please Enter Tweet";
```

Note that, since `newTweet` had only one element anyway, there was no need for the following loop:

```
for(String name: newTweet) { ... }
```

So you should remove the `for`, and pass `newTweet` as argument to `addTextfield()`:

```
cp5.addTextfield(newTweet)
   .setPosition(200,y)
   .setSize(500,60)
   .setColorBackground(0xffffffff)
   .setFont(font)
   .setFocus(true)
   .setColor(color(10,10,255));
```

Comment: There is that, you can also pass the first value of the array like `newTweet[0]`

Comment: Yeah I tried that before, but then got the error message "can only iterate over an array or an instance of java.lang.iterable, highlighting the following code: 'for(String name: newTweet)' (Where you format the text input box).

Answer (score 0):

`updateStatus` method accepts single String as a parameter and you are passing string array.

Multiple ways you can solve this:

```
Status status = twitter.updateStatus(newTweet[0]);//if you just want first element from array
```

OR

```
String newTweet = "Please Enter Tweet";//you just have one element, so dont use array
```

Or

```
for (String tweet : newTweet) {//if you need array and all the elements of an array
     Status status = twitter.updateStatus(tweet);
     ...
}
```